# Automatically Retrieving Album Names for Unknown Album Songs in iTunes

Tags: itunes, music

I'm running `iTunes 11.1.2` on `OSX Mavericks` and have a bunch of songs of *unknown albums*. I know that we can retrieve *album artwork* from the *album name*, but that's not what I am interested in. What I would like to know is wether it is possible or not to retrieve **album name** for each song I have given only **song name** and **artist name** (and maybe the song file itself, of course).

All I found when searching for it is the *unknown album problem* when updating iTunes, or the *album artwork* retrieval from *album name*. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Tagalicious](http://thelittleappfactory.com/tagalicious/)

Whilst it has been discontinued, Tagalicious has worked well for me for a long time, finding accurate results to missing info on music in my iTunes library.

### [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard)

A cross-platform ID3 tag finder for songs. Despite the fact that it doesn't integrate with iTunes specifically, the ID3 tags can be read by iTunes.